# While / do-while loop doesn't end

Tags: java, loops

As far as I know, the logic in conditional and loop statements are the same whether it is C# or Java.

```
class WhileLoops {

public static void main(String args[]){


Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String answer = "";
/*do{

    System.out.println("Will you be my girlfriend?(Yes/No)");
    answer = input.nextLine();
    }while(answer != "Yes" && answer != "Yes");*/

while(answer != "Yes" && answer != "yes") {

    System.out.println("Will you be my girlfriend?(Yes/No)");
    answer = input.nextLine();
    }

System.out.println("I promise to make you feel special.");

   }
}
```

as you can see in the code above I used do-while and while just setting either one as a comment when I will compile and run.

This is what happens when I run the program:
[image: 1]

Comment: Your code writes out an image? Please copy your sample input and output into your question! There is no need for an image here.

Comment: Is it hard to load? Okay will do better next time thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.equals()` method. 
So,

```
while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {... }
```

The reason for this is that Java compares *references* when using the `==` operator. When you compare the two strings they point at different places in memory, and so the comparison fails.

The `equals()` (and `equalsIgnoreCase()`) methods compare the actual contents of the block of memory.

Note: This is only true for reference types (like strings and other classes). Value types (like ints and floats etc) can be compared with the usual equals operators.

Comment: Thanks for your very specific and informative answer! Highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
while(!answer.toLowerCase().equals("yes"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)